# How to redirect from error-page preRenderView in JSF 2.2?

Tags: ajax, jsf, redirect, jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I wanted to upgrade JSF 2.1 (myfaces) to 2.2 in my application. I just changed two myfaces....jar files in TomEE/lib folder (TomEE-1.7.5). Everything seems to work well except one thing. I have an error page configured in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/500.jsf</location>
</error-page>
```

In order to catch error in case of ajax post, omnifaces' FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory is declared in faces-config.xml:

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

In error page there is a *preRenderView* function, in which there is a conditional redirect. In JSF 2.1 it was working perfectly. But with JSF 2.2 in case of redirection, because of some other exception I get this message:

> Oops!
>
> A problem occurred during processing the ajax request. Subsequently,
>   another problem occurred during processing the error page which should
>   inform you about that problem.

The other exception in log:

> SEVERE: FullAjaxExceptionHandler: Well, another exception occurred
>   during rendering error page '/error/500.jsf'. Trying to render a
>   hardcoded error page now. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot
>   change buffer size after data has been written

I tried to use something other event handler instead of *preRenderView* (I thought maybe the redirection should be made at an earlier point of the lifecycle(?)). With *postAddToView* event the result is the same, other events are not called at all.

Also instead of *f:event* I tried to use *f:viewAction* of JSF 2.2, but in case of ajax post none of the possible viewAction events is called on the error page (onPostback="true" parameter also did not help).

**Questions:**

Why I get the other exception on error page in case of redirection? (There was no any problem with myfaces 2.1)

Why viewAction function is not called at all on error page? (when the error resulted to go to the error page occured in an ajax request)

**So how to make (conditional) redirect from error-page with JSF (myfaces) 2.2?**